# How to detect sudden bottleneck in mysql with 2000%CPU

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, memory

Our nginx-mysql server has been running smoothly for months (even years) . All of the sudden mysql consume around 700-2000% CPU , very little RAM. even after `mysql restart`, the usage goes up right off. Nginx CPU/RAM usage is minimal (since the traffic is just at 20% of peak). Turning off nginx solved it proving some queries were having problem.  **The question is how to pinpoint the troublemaker one.** any command or query to do so (from bash, nginx, log etc..)?

FYI: I did optimize and repair all the tables but did not work. The problem was solved when I truncate 2 "middle size" table of 2M rows. Those 2 tables used to behave normally with 20M+ rows, and they have good indexes...  I did purge/truncate the large tables from time to time.

Edit 1: mysql-slow.log did help a little but not right to the point

Comment: Are you using MyISAM or InnoDB as the engine?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen : I think it is MyISAM. most of the tables are myIsam

Comment: You should convert to InnoDB, in general it always outperforms MyISAM.

Comment: Turn on the slowlog.  When you find some slow queries, let's discuss them.  Possibly the solution is as simple as adding an index.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` in MySQL console to display all running queries.